# Explicit Solution to Lippmann-Schwinger Equation in Weinberg QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, scattering

I am not sure whether this question has been asked (or answered) before.

In *Problem 1* of *Chapter 3* of *QFT Volume 1*, Weinberg asks us to find the **explicit solution** for the 'in' and 'out' states from the *Lippmann-Schwinger* equation, given the conditions,
$$\langle\Phi_\beta|V\Phi_\alpha\rangle=gu_\beta u_\alpha^*$$
and that,
$$\sum_\alpha u^*_\alpha u_\alpha=1$$
I am not sure whether we have to take the Born approximation to $\mathcal{O}(2)$, or is there a way to find a solution without resorting to any approximation.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Lippmann-Schwinger equation is an approximation if you don't push the iteration to infinity, and Born approximation is derived from it so I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @Turgon Thanks. I completely get it. I was wondering whether for this problem, this infinite series sums up nicely to give a complete and exact answer.